# How to properly use route on ajax call when defining a datatable in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, model-view-controller, datatable

Hello guys i am new to laravel and i want to use jquery datatable for a simple crud.My main problem is with the server side part of the datatable. I use my route to controller for ajax request when i want to get data for datatables but it seems that it's  just concat a string to url so here is a snippet:

```
 $('#table_id').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ !! route('admin.users.index') !!}}",
            "method": "GET",
            "columns": [
                {"data":'nume', "name":'nume'},
                {"data":'email', "name":'email'},
                {"data":'drept', "name":'drept'},
                {"data":'action', "name":'action', "orderable":false}
            ]
        });


Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){

    Route::resource('/users' ,'UsersControler', ['except'=>['show','create','store']]);

});
```

And this is the url that the app is trying to reach Request URL:

http://10.10.10.119:8080/admin/%7B%7B%20!!%20route('admin.users.index')%20!!%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on this line: (double "{" and double "!")

```
"ajax": "{{ !! route('admin.users.index') !!}}",
```

Try this:

```
"ajax": "{!! route('admin.users.index') !!}",
```

Comment: @Andrei 
I'm doing this in all of my projects. That's strange... Try clear cached views using this command: php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
"ajax": "{{ !! route('admin.users.index') !! }}",
```

with

```
"ajax": "{{ route('admin.users.index') }}",
```

Comment: i think it's a problem from jquery .I am trying to reinstall jquery and i am comming back with news.